# How to improve the UX/UI for multiple buttons that are now spread out

Tags: interaction-design

I am working on a web application where we have detail pages for applications that were submitted by the user and certificates that were issued for them.These pages have multiple buttons and are spread out. I am not sure the design that we have is good user experience as there might be other buttons later for download. What would be a better solution for this from UX and UI perspective? Thanks in advance for help

[image: Application Details]

[image: Certification Details]

Comment: You should reformulate the question about a specific topic, as you ask it, it looks like a Site Review and this is off-topic.

Comment: Reframed the question. I hope this is good. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve the user experience.
Use the principle of proximity to correctly position the buttons. Observe the hierarchy of elements, for this use different types of buttons (primary, secondary, tertiary). Make visual accents so that the user quickly finds the information of interest to him.
Also, look at examples of good forms (I've added some below), this will give you a better idea of what to look for.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is understand what "Better" means in this situation. Is it a 'faster' experience? Is it a 'more satisfying' experience? etc.

Once you have that, then you can start to map out all the possible combinations of controls and buttons to work out which need to be static (staying in the same place allowing the user to build a muscle memory), which need to be varied (to ensure no accidental operation) and which can be either. Use the context of what 'better' means to help you resolve any problematic situations.

There's no generalised solution for this as every product has different needs.

Lastly, if in doubt ask your users. - Run some task-based user testing sessions on a few different iterations of button arrangements and see which performs the best.